# Exception handling with method overriding in Java doesn't make sense

Tags: java, exception

In an article (here's the link: https://www.javatpoint.com/exception-handling-with-method-overriding)
they said that :
*"If the superclass method does not declare an exception, subclass overridden method cannot declare the checked exception but it can declare an unchecked exception."*

Why does Java work this way? Since the overridden method can have more features than the superclass's method, it can throw some exceptions that the superclass's method won't throw.

Answer (score 4):

> why java works this way?

To support polymorphism and maintain the idea of checked exceptions. The point of checked exceptions is to tell the caller, "Hey, this method might throw this checked exception - you need to catch it or declare that you might throw it too". Suppose you had:

```java
Superclass x = new Subclass();
x.doSomething();
```

... if `Superclass.doSomething()` doesn't declare that it can throw any checked exceptions, but the override of it in `Subclass` *does* throw a checked exception, the compiler can't "know" that, so it can't check it.